# Linux command from python to execute inside subfolders

Tags: python, linux

This is my folder structure:

```
ORDERNO'S  YEAR'S  MONTH'S  DATE'S  CSVFILES
408------->2010---->01-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
    ------->201101-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
    ------->201201-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
    ------->2013--01-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ----->02-->21--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
                      --->22--->1.CSV
                           --->2.CSV
               ...
```

As their are many csv files inside a particular date.
i want to combine all csv file inside each date folder with header of 1st file only into one single file and name is as orderno_year_month_date.csv.
means every datefolder will have have only one csv named after their parent folders.So,
i want clean command for this in linux which i can run outside of ORDERNO directory or execute same command using python script such that i don't have to go again and again inside folder and manually execute the command.

**This same question is posted in askubuntu 3 months before but no answers there.

Expected structure should be like

```
ORDERNO'S  YEAR'S  MONTH'S  DATE'S  CSVFILES
408------->2010---->01-->21--->408_2010_01_21.CSV
                      --->22--->408_2010_01_22.CSV
                      ...
```

Previously i was going to each date folders of each month folder of each year folder of each order no. and use to run this command for single file for header.

```
awk '(NR == 1) || (FNR > 1)' *.csv > 4011_2020_07_16.csv  (example)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be using this mock file structure (plotted using the `tree` command, and saved under `~/test/` in my computer):

```sh
test
└── 408
    └── 2010
        └── 01
            ├── 21
            │   ├── 1.csv
            │   └── 2.csv
            ├── 22
            │   ├── 1.csv
            │   └── 2.csv
            └── 23
                ├── 1.csv
                └── 2.csv
```

You can rename the files using Python, with the help of `pathlib` and concatenate  them using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path

def getfolders(files):
    return sorted(list(set([file.parent for file in files])))

def getpathproperty(folder, prop):
    properties = {"orderno": 3, "year": 2, "month": 1, "day": 0}
    for i in range(properties[prop]):
        folder = folder.parent
    return folder.stem

path = Path("~/test").expanduser()
allfiles = list(path.rglob("*.csv")) # Each file in allfiles is a Path object

folders = getfolders(allfiles)

for folder in folders:
    files = sorted(list(folder.glob("*.csv")))
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])

    # Get the values from the path to rename the files
    orderno = getpathproperty(folder, "orderno")
    year = getpathproperty(folder, "year")
    month = getpathproperty(folder, "month")
    day = getpathproperty(folder, "day")

    # Save the new CSV file
    df.to_csv(folder/f"{orderno}_{year}_{month}_{day}.csv", index=False)

    # Delete old files, commented for safety
    # for file in files:
        # file.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

This yields:

```sh
test
└── 408
    └── 2010
        └── 01
            ├── 21
            │   └── 408_2010_01_21.csv
            ├── 22
            │   └── 408_2010_01_22.csv
            └── 23
                └── 408_2010_01_23.csv
```

Comment: perfect i will try this in the evening.

Comment: @NavinMishra please accept the answer if it solved your problem.